# Compare Latest CSV with all CSV in directory and remove the matching from the latest and write new rows in new file with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

the code will not work properly e.g. when the name of files are something else.

for example when the file name is carre123.csv, it wont compare correctly. but when I changed the file name to test123.csv it works fine.

here is the code

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Set the directory where the CSV files are stored
directory = '/PATH/csv-files'

# Get a list of all the CSV files in the directory
csv_files = [os.path.join(directory, f) for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.csv')]
#print(csv_files)

# Sort the CSV files by modification time and select the last file as the latest file
latest_file = sorted(csv_files, key=os.path.getmtime)[-1]
#print(latest_file)

# Read the contents of the latest CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
latest_data = pd.read_csv(latest_file)
#print(latest_data)

# Iterate over all the previous CSV files
for csv_file in csv_files[:-1]:
    # Read the contents of the previous CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
    prev_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    #print(prev_data)

    # Identify the rows in the latest CSV file that match the rows in the previous CSV file
    matches = latest_data.isin(prev_data.to_dict('list')).all(axis=1)
    print(matches)

    # Remove the matching rows from the latest CSV file
    latest_data = latest_data[~matches]

# Write the remaining rows in the latest CSV file to a new file
latest_data.to_csv('/NEWPATH/diff.csv', index=False)
```

when the file name is carre123.csv, it wont compare correctly. but when I changed the file name to test123.csv it works fine.

Comment: What exactly means "won't compare correctly"?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has a bug, which may be what is causing the problem. The `for` loop is over `csv_files[:-1]` which is not sorted by modification time, so depending on the file names this may cause the loop to include `latest_file`. Try storing the sorted list, `sorted(csv_files, key=os.path.getmtime)`, then select the last one for `latest_file` and loop over the remaining files. Maybe there is something else wrong too, but based on the example you provided, this looks like the only issue I can see that is obviously a problem.